# VB How do i recall a line of text from a text file, based on user selection?

Tags: vb.net, file, text, streamreader

This is what i have so far...

```
    Dim Test As String = "C:\test.txt"
    Dim User As String


    Console.WriteLine("What user password would you like?")
    User = Console.ReadLine().ToLower
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Test)

    While Not objReader.EndOfStream

        If User.Contains("Admin1") Then


            Console.WriteLine(objReader.ReadLine())

        End If
    End While

    objReader.Close()
```

I'm not sure whether or not there is something needed to go in the brackets of the " (objReader.ReadLine() " If anyone could help that would be fantastic, thanks.

Comment: it might help if you added some lines of your test.txt file. From what I can see you are comparing the user input with the constant "Admin1". So unless the User enters Admin1 you will run into an endless loop. What you probably want to do is a) read a line and store it in a local variable and b) compare the value of the local variable with the value of your User variable.

Comment: admin1; "Your password is Password1"
admin2; "Your password is Password2"

This is the kind of thing i was going for. I was trying to use the semi colon as i thought it is used to separate the strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want...

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
    Dim Line As String = sr.ReadLine()
    While Line IsNot Nothing
        If Line.Contains("Admin1") Then
            Console.WriteLine(Line)
        End If
        Line = sr.ReadLine()
    End While
End Using
```

The "Using" block ensures that the StreamReader object is automatically closed and disposed without you needing to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! If i wanted to improve this by identifying just the 


   'Admin1'

If the user were to say "I would like the password for Admin1'? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I wouldn't be able to answer that without knowing the format of the input file.

Comment: admin1; password1
admin2; password2 and so on.. 
    Again, appreciate your help!

Comment: You could use the String.Split() method to split the line at the semicolon and then you'd get an array where element 0 is the username and element 1 is the password.

Comment: When you have a moment, I'd be grateful if you marked my answer as "Accepted". :)